# API received information from calls is appended with extra characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller for my API for Rails app.However, messages received are appended with 6 underscores. `@message.message = CGI.unescape(params[:message]).strip` has the `@message.message` string appended with an extra 6 underscores.
For example;
`@message.message` for xample ends up with the value `"Hi, Joseph and Beatrice invite you for our wedding day preparation meetings Fridays, starting 5/10/2012 at Calvary Chapel Kampala - William Street Gadith ______"`
The controller is as shown below;

```
def sms
    @message = Message.new
    decoded_to = CGI.unescape(params[:to])
    #@message.to = decoded_to.gsub(/[^\d]/,"")
    @message.to = CGI.unescape(params[:to]).strip.gsub("+","").gsub(/\s+/, "")
    @message.from =  CGI.unescape(params[:from])
    @message.message = CGI.unescape(params[:message]).strip
    @message.user_id = current_user.id
    @message.status = 'Queued'
    if @message.save
        MessageWorker.perform_async(@message.id, [""], current_user.id)
        render json: {status: "Success"} 
    else
        render json: {status: "Failed" }
    end
end
```

What could be the problem?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: What does the params[:message] value looks like for your example? "Hi, Joseph..."

Comment: Why are you unescaping the parameters? Rails already provides an unescaped params hash! Just don't!